# Can I use chestnut roaster clay pot to roast coffee at home?

Tags: coffee, roasting

I got the attached clay pot chestnut roaster. Can I use it to roast coffee at home?
[image: this clay chestnut roaster]

Answer (score 1):

I believe so. Technically you can use the hood of your car. Rosting coffee (and nuts) is about the heat, not the material. Just keep the heat gentle, give it its 15 minutes or so and don't "french roast" is to death.

And tell how it came out.

Comment: Movement is important as well to roasting nuts of any kind, every home made roaster I think I have seen makes sure to have the item moving to help insure even heating.